# Export title of pages in mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

Is there a way to export a list of all pages in MediaWiki.

I've had a look at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Export but it offers no solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the specal page "export" is used to export the content of a page to a file to import it in another MediaWiki.

If you just need a list of all the pages why don't you just use the special page [AllPages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:AllPages) and copy&paste it to an spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [allpages API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Allpages), or simply query the `page` table. [`generateSitemap.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:GenerateSitemap.php) also does it for you but probably not in the format you would want.